# forEach in angular modification array

Tags: foreach

I want to change the value of these elements with a "trim ()".

"this.currentPaaas.Requisicion.RefCFinancingFirst [0] = this.currentPaaas.Requisicion [0] .RefCFinancingForm.trim ();"

"this.currentPaaas.Requisicion [0] .RefCObjetoGasto = this.currentPaaas.Requisicion [0] .RefCObjetoGasto.trim ();"

But they are inside an array, the way I do it only changes a single value within the array.
How can I change all the values ​​within that array?

currentPaaas contains the array Requisicion []

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgWKa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what has been stated in the question,i think what you are trying to do is to trim RefCFinancingForm of each element in currentPaaas?

If yes,This is what you need:
this.currentPaaas.Requisicion.forEach(x=>x.RefCFinancingForm =x.RefCFinancingForm.trim())

Comment: Great !, you are the master hahaha, thank you man. I would donate you a million pesos, but I do not have them